# patch broke my saved powershell secure strings

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, password-encryption

I wonder if others noticed too. I have a powershell script connecting via new-pssession to some other machines (windows servers) and the credentials are saved as XML via

```
$credential = Get-Credential
$credential| export-clixml somepath.xml
```

After september updates it can no longer import those XML files because

```
Import-CliXml : Key not valid for use in specified state.
```

If I recreate them again with the same credential set it works again! But I see the string in there is different! Seems like some crypto have changed and I will have to recreate all those saved credentials :-\

Is it possible patch caused this or am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: What is the question?  It may be related to this:  https://techdows.com/2020/06/chrome-issues-on-windows-10-may-2020-update.html

The google bug also has additional details: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1069383#c27

Comment: I am sorry how is this related to Chrome in any way??
The question is what this Import-CliXml error means and if it's true my saved credentials got broken by a patch. This is about Windows Server and powershell. I don't use Chrome Browser there

Comment: Did you change windows password at some point? That would break it.

Comment: Yes I did, some time ago. That would never occur to me that it can break it and error message really doesn't help realizing that! I thought my password should not matter and break this file format. That's a surprise to me

Comment: I don't really understand what is the intended us of this powershell functionality, because it is quite normal practice to change your password isn't it?

Comment: Yeah it's annoying. I've put in the comment as an answer for the next person to try this.

Comment: `ConvertFrom-SecureString` allows you to specify your own key, but this makes you responsible for key management.  By default export-clixml uses DPAPI, which has the limitations described in the comment and in the article about Chrome I linked earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, the encryption is based on current windows user (including password).

To import the xml after changing windows password, you'll have to export it again first.

There's a new vault module from MS to serve a similar purpose, but it's still a work-in-progress at the moment. Maybe more relevant to future readers.

For more information - https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-export-xml/
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Protection_API

Comment: Still I really wonder, because PowerShell is already quite old, so how can this be used if it's dependent on the account's password? I guess there must be some other preferred way to deal with this which would be useful and not break with every password change, is there?

Comment: maybe make a special account with restricted permissions and non expiring password which would be used to manage stored credentials, but then I am not sure how would I interact with it from some other scripts running under my normal admin account. How would they ask that password managing script for some credentials? I am no PowerShell expert so I don't know if there is a preferred way or some inter process communication. Of course I could use windows registry to exchange information, but that's not very secure probably...

Comment: @McVitas even if you make a russian nesting doll of passwords, you then have to manually enter the password of the other account, which defeats the point of storing passwords. There is some existing vault software on the market, for example keepass. Hopefully https://github.com/powershell/SecretManagement is good once it's complete and polished.